# Unable to receive Cookie in HttpServletRequest contain JSON Format value

Tags: javascript, java, json, servlets

I have added two cookies through Javascript.

1. Test

   ```
   document.cookie = "test=testCookie; expires=Fri, 16 Oct 2015 22:24:05 GMT; path=/";
   ```
2. Actual Data

   ```
   document.cookie = "item="+JSON.stringify(itemsJSON)+"; expires=Fri, 16 Oct 2015 22:24:05 GMT; path=/";
   ```

On server side in HttpServletRequest request object, i am able to get "test" cookie but not "item" cookie. When i remove JSON value from "item" cookien and just add a dummy string value then i am able to get "item" cookie in request. That's means there is problem with HttpServletRequest that is unable to receive JSON value cookies.

**Is there any solution to receive cookies (contains JSON formatted values) in HttpServletRequest object.**

Comment: I'd suggest converting the json to Base64 then decoding it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not on your server side! In case you can retrieve cookies by name properly from the `HttpServletRequest` object then your server code is fine.

The problem should be that your JavaScript call does not return a valid output before request submit. In case your JS has access to `JSON.stringify()` object's function on your document then the itemsJSON var is not collected / not available in your browser before your HTTP request is sent through the wire and for this reason the cookie is simply not created and attached to your request.

I would use JS debugger in your preferred browser. Chrome dev tool's or Mozilla Web Developer plugin should help to check the value of your var before `send`.

Comment: itemsJSON exist. I have done with debugging. All things are working fine. Browser is also showing cookies as well. In browser cookies there is item cookie with JSON value but i am unable to get that cookies on server side.

Comment: what about the size of your itemsJSON and cookies? The size of all cookies should not exceed 4093 bytes. This means you can have 1 cookie of 4093 bytes, or 2 cookies of 2045 bytes...